# find all documents with common fields mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a `users` collection:

```
{
  id: usera@acme.com,
  uid: '57672373683'
}

{
  id: userb@acme.com,
  uid: '25346346221'
}

{
  id: userc@acme.com,
  uid: '57672373683'
}
```

I would like to run a query that will return all of the users with common `uid` field, for example here I will see usera and userc together because they have the same `uid` field.

Is it possible with a query in mongo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group users by using Aggregation Framework. The query will be like :

```
db.users.aggregate({$group : {_id : "$uid", users : {$addToSet : "$id"}}})
```

Results will look like :

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : "25346346221",
        "users" : [
            "userb@acme.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "57672373683",
        "users" : [
            "userc@acme.com",
            "usera@acme.com"
        ]
    }
]
```